# Rav Elyashiv Rabbanut Hilchos Niddah Kuntres

Tags: sources-mekorot, niddah

Someone who lived in Eretz Yisroel many years ago mentioned that Rav [Yosef Shalom Elyashiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yosef_Shalom_Elyashiv) zt"l wrote a small kuntres under the Rabbanut of the absolute basic halachos of niddah. Is that kuntres available to read online?